# does android system guarantee send SMS callback method onReceive() must be called?

Tags: android, sms

When i send a  SMS by the android api sendTextMessage (), and init a pendingIntent to monitor the  sending SMS status. Does android system guarantee it must be called the onReceive() method in the near furture? anyone answer would be appreciated!

Comment: before i sent a sms, i have new a intentFilter as :               IntentFilter            intentFilter            = new IntentFilter (ACTION_SMS_SENT);
                intentFilter.setPriority (INTENT_FILTER_PRIORITY);
                _context.registerReceiver (this, intentFilter);

Comment: of course i send sms from the broadcast receiver which i created, maybe i'm not clear my question, my confuse is does the android guarantee to call back the onReceive, cause i will implement a loading  view to waitting the sms callback, if android would not call back, the loading view will always be there, that is really really bad.